# Map array image elements horizontally

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to map images in an array horizontally, but they're being mapped vertically no matter what I do.

```
    const numberOfRows = Math.ceil(images.length / 3); 

    const result = Array(numberOfRows)
      .fill()
      .map((_, rowIndex) => (
        <View key={rowIndex}>
          {images
            .slice(rowIndex * 5, rowIndex * 5 + 5)
            .map((image, imageIndex) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={imageIndex}
                onPress={() => alert("image pressed!")}
              >
                <Image
                  source={{
                    uri:
                      "https://miro.medium.com/max/814/1*Cxm5opOziPF5iavnDSYHLg.png"
                  }}
                  style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
        </View>
      ));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard flex-direction of a View is vertical. By adding `flexDirection: 'row'` to your parent View, you can overwrite this behavior.

**Code**

```
<View key={rowIndex} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
...
</View>
```

**Working Snack:**

https://snack.expo.io/rygY2Vb3H

Answer (score 0):

By default react-native View flex-direction was column. So to align vertically add `flexDirection: 'row'` to view :

```js
<View key={rowIndex} style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
... // your image map code
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **flexDirection** to your **View**.

```
<View key={rowIndex} style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
...
</View>
```

You can read more about [flexDirection from here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox).